# How to give Relative Path in Mule File Read?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

Hi I created a folder and placed a sample XML file in src/main/resources/samplexml/samplxml.xml.
File Config i did as

```
<file:config name="File_Config" doc:name="File Config">
    <file:connection workingDir="${app.home}" />
</file:config>
```

In File Read operation i configured it as

```
<file:read doc:name="Read" config-ref="File_Config" path="/samplexml/samplxml.xml"/>
```

But when run the application i get error as

```
Message               : Path '/samplexml/samplxml.xml' doesn't exist
Error type            : FILE:ILLEGAL_PATH
```

What is the correct way of giving relative path ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the heading slash in the 'Read' operation 'Path' property:

```
<file:read doc:name="Read" config-ref="File_Config" path="samplexml/samplxml.xml"/>
```